# Convert hash string to binary file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, hex, sha

What would be the easiest way to convert the text produced by utilities such as `sha512sum` into a binary file?

I'd like to convert hex string like `77f4de214a5423e3c7df8704f65af57c39c55f08424c75c0931ab09a5bfdf49f5f939f2caeff1e0113d9b3d6363583e4830cf40787100b750cde76f00b8cd3ec` (example produced by `sha512sum`) into a binary file (64 bytes long), in which each byte's value would be equivalent to a pair of letters/digits from the string. I'm looking for a solution that would require minimal amount of tools, so I'd be happy if this can be done easily with `bash`, `sed` or some utility from coreutils. I'd rather avoid `xxd`, as this doesn't seem to handle such string anyway (I'd have to add "addresses" and some whitespace).

I need the hash as a binary file, to convert it into an object file and link with the application that I'm writing. If there's another way to embed such string (in a binary form!) into application (via an array or whatever) - it's also a solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of `sed` and `echo` might do:

```
for i in $(echo 77f4de214a5423e3c7df8704f65af57c39c55f08424c75c0931ab09a5bfdf49f5f939f2caeff1e0113d9b3d6363583e4830cf40787100b750cde76f00b8cd3ec | sed 's/../& /g'); do
   echo -ne "\x$i"
done > output.bin
```

The `sed` command is splitting the hex string into bytes and the `echo` shows it as hexadecimal character.

Or in a shorter form with `sha512sum` output, as suggested in the comment:

```
echo -ne "$(sha512sum some-file.txt | sed 's/ .*$//; s/../\\x&/g')"
```

Comment: I managed to do that without a loop: `sha512sum somefile.ext | grep -o '[0-9a-f]\{128\}' | echo -en $(sed 's/\([0-9a-f]\{2\}\)/\\x\1/g') > hash.bin`. Seems a bit shorter than the looping construct.

Answer (score 2):

How about perl:

```
<<<77f4de214a5423e3c7df8704f65af57c39c55f08424c75c0931ab09a5bfdf49f5f939f2caeff1e0113d9b3d6363583e4830cf40787100b750cde76f00b8cd3ec \
perl -e 'print pack "H*", <STDIN>' > hash.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `openssl` in your system and want a sha512 hash in binary form, you can use this:

```
openssl dgst -sha512 -binary somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have node:

```
node -e "var fs = require('fs'); fs.writeFileSync('binary', new Buffer('77f4de214a5423e3c7df8704f65af57c39c55f08424c75c0931ab09a5bfdf49f5f939f2caeff1e0113d9b3d6363583e4830cf40787100b750cde76f00b8cd3ec', 'hex'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s="77f4de214a5423e3c7df8704f65af57c39c55f08424c75c0931ab09a5bfdf49f5f939f2caeff1e0113d9b3d6363583e4830cf40787100b750cde76f00b8cd3ec"; 
echo -n $s | xxd -r -p > file.bin

 1 File(s)             64 bytes
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.7